# How to do this has_one through?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to do this association, where:

Team `has_one` User `through` Captain

Captain.rb

```
class Captain < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :team
```

Team.rb

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
has_one :user, through: :captain
end
```

User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

has_one :captain
belongs_to :team
has_many :invites
has_and_belongs_to_many :games
has_one :captain

end
```

and the following error around line 27:

```
NoMethodError in TeamsController#create

26 def create
*27 @team = current_user.teams.create(team_params)*
28 @team.save
29 respond_with(@team)
30 current_user.update(team_id: @team.id)
```

Thanks...

Comment: I can put external image link? [link]http://s564.photobucket.com/user/spowtt/media/assosiation_error.jpg.html

already tried to put team rather than teams. It's the same error!
Thanks.

Comment: Because the team has one user, and you are creating the team and assigning to an existing user, you can do `@team = Team.create(team_params)` then `current_user.team = @team`.

Comment: tks lurker its work!!! lol
but he doesnt write in the table captain....=/

Comment: Up-ticking answers you find useful encourages others to spend time on your question... Wave your mouse to the right of lurkers answer and hit the up arrow.